# Change woocommerce thank you text

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add custom text after a successful order. I found this code which works fine

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'coupon_thankyou', 10, 2 ); 

function coupon_thankyou( $order_id ) {

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

     $total=0;

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {

         $item_data = $item->get_data();       

         $item_total = intval( $item_data[‘total’] );

         $total += $item_total;        

}

if ( $total>100 ) {

echo "<section class='woocommerce-thankyou-coupon'><h2 class='woocommerce-column__title'>Congrats! Get 50% off your next purchase!</h2><div class='tybox'><p>As a special thanks for spending over $100 with us today, we’d like to give you 50% off your next order of any full priced items in our store.</p><p>Use code <code class='tycoupon'>[ 50special ]</code>&nbsp;on your next order.</p></div></section>";

}

}
```

The problem is that the custom text is added at the end of the html page as last element. How can I put it on the top?